# Azure Functions Packet Capture and Network Trace

Tags: azure, azure-functions, packet-capture

Is there a way to use Azure Network Watcher or any other service to capture packets from an Azure Functions App? I have tried with Azure Network Watcher, but it only gives me an option to capture packets from a VM. The functions app is hosted on an App Service Plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found that "Diagnose and solve problems" option on function app blade can be used to collect Network Trace.

Diagnose and solve problems --> Diagnostic Tools --> Collect Network Trace --> Choose duration to collect the Network Trace and then click on "Collect Network Trace". If the Functions app has multiple instances, Network Trace will be collected for all of the instances.

[image: Collect Network Trace Option Location Screenshot]