# Azure Functions Collect Network Trace for a Linux app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, tcpdump, packet-capture

*TL;DR: What can I do to capture packets when the "Collect Network Trace" facility is not available?*

I have an Azure Function App running on a linux app service plan, which is seeing some issues with TCP connection resets. To debug the issue I would like to capture network traffic.

I have seen [another question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70836026/azure-functions-packet-capture-and-network-trace) which asks this same question. In that case the accepted answer would be ideal (i.e. Diagnose and solve problems --> Diagnostic Tools --> Collect Network Trace --> Choose duration to collect the Network Trace and then click on "Collect Network Trace".)

However, in my case that facility is not available to me:

[image: Azure dashboard showing limited diagnostic tools available]

What can I do to capture packets when the packet capture facility is not an option? Is there some context in which I could run tcpdump, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could find is to install and run `tcpdump` using the Web SSH shell in the Azure portal.

[Development Tools] -> [SSH] -> [Go]

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install tcpdump
tcpdump --version
```

Far from ideal, but at least it's something!

Answer (score 0):

***It seems this feature is not available for linux or any container yet as shown in the portal***

[image]

AFAIK, To capture packets when the "Collect Network Trace" facility is not available, We can use Auto-Healing as steps are provided in this [**`Blog|Collect Network Trace Via Autohealing on Azure App Service`**](https://puneet-gupta.github.io/puneetgupta/2020/06/01/collect-network-trace-via-AutoHealing/) by @***Punnet Gupta***.

*Alternatively you can refer this* [***MICRSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-alert-triggered-packet-capture) *for more information.*